# How to download Gmail attachment from linux console?

Tags: linux, gmail

I've logged into gmail and have link to attachment. I'm logging to remote linux console and need to dowload this attachment, but can't download it by wget. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Log in to your Gmail with a web browser and download the file. Elinks is easy to use.

  ```
  elinks https://mail.google.com/
  ```
- Enable IMAP in Gmail settings, then log in using an IMAP client and download the file.

  ```
  mutt -f imaps://imap.gmail.com

  alpine -f "{imap.gmail.com/ssl}"
  ```